# How to get R date time format from mixed date time informats

Tags: r

Hi I have date_time column as "Factor" type which is having mixed date_time as below. How to change these informats to R datetime format

```
date_time                  R_date_time
01-Apr-2017 12:00:00       2017-04-01 12:00:00 
02/04/2017  03:00:00       2017-04-02 03:00:00 
30/05/2017  06:15:00       2017-05-30 06:15:00
2/4/2017    05:18:00       2017-04-02 05:18:00
2017/12/31  20:30:00       2017-12-31 20:30:00
```

Comment: It can be easily done with the anytime package e.g.: anytime(date_time, tz = "UTC")

Comment: yes i am facing this problem earlier

Comment: you could add the other formats using addFormats()

Comment: for example: anytime::addFormats(c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%Y/%d/%m %H:%M:%S")) ; anytime("30/05/2017 06:15:00")

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lubridate`:

```
> dmy_hms("01-Apr-2017 12:00:00")
[1] "2017-04-01 12:00:00 UTC"

> dmy_hms("02/04/2017  03:00:00")
[1] "2017-04-02 03:00:00 UTC"

> dmy_hms("30/05/2017  06:15:00")
[1] "2017-05-30 06:15:00 UTC"

> ymd_hms("2017/12/31  20:30:00 ")
[1] "2017-12-31 20:30:00 UTC"

> dmy_hms("2/4/2017    05:18:00")#ambiguous format you can use mdy_hms as well
[1] "2017-04-02 05:18:00 UTC"
```

OR:

```
> mdy_hms("2/4/2017    05:18:00")
[1] "2017-02-04 05:18:00 UTC"

>ymd_hms("2017/12/31  20:30:00")
[1] "2017-12-31 20:30:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `anytime` package is a great alternative. For instance:

```
date_time <- c(text = "01-Apr-2017 12:00:00", "02/04/2017 03:00:00", 
               "30/05/2017 06:15:00", "2/4/2017 05:18:00", "2017/12/31 20:30:00")
```

You need to add some of the formats using `addFormats()` e.g.:

```
library(anytime)
anytime::addFormats(c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")) 

anytime(date_time, tz = "UTC")

[1] "2017-04-01 12:00:00 UTC" "2017-04-02 03:00:00 UTC" "2017-05-30 06:15:00 UTC"
[4] NA                        "2017-12-31 20:30:00 UTC"
```

However, it seems like `anytime()` can't parse those like "2/4/2017 05:18:00". See e.g. https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/issues/24. In that case you could use `lubridate:dmy_hms("2/4/2017 05:18:00")` or simply `strptime("2/4/2017 05:18:00", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")`

Comment: The results from `anytime(R_date_time, tz = "UTC")` Don't look like the input dates; e.g. `01-Apr-2017 12:00:00` becoming `2017-03-31 22:00:00 UTC`.  I suspect it's a timezone thing, but not sure.

Comment: @MarijnStevering, It works well for me: anytime("01-Apr-2017 12:00:00", asUTC = TRUE, tz = "UTC") #"2017-04-01 12:00:00 UTC".